# Creating a new column in RVest based on a cascading variable

Tags: r, web-scraping, tidyverse, rvest

I'm writing a data scraper in using `rvest` which looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

targets_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/college/ohio-state/Season/2021-Football/Targets/")

targets <- map_df(targets_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                          html_nodes(".ri-page__star-and-score .score , .position , .meta , .ri-page__name-link") %>%
                          html_text() %>% 
                          str_trim %>% 
                          str_split("   ") %>% 
                          matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>% 
                          as.data.frame)

df_structure <- apply(targets,2,as.character)

df_targets <- as.data.frame(df_structure)
```

You'll notice that it creates a dataframe with four variables and 53 rows.

But now go to the URL itself. You'll notice that the 53 rows correspond to certain subcategorizations: Top Target, High Choice, and Interested. Here's a picture showing an example:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is create a fifth column, which contains the subcategory. So for example, the three individuals who fall under "Top Target" will be assigned another column which lists them as "Top Target". Then the next 20 rows will have that fifth column reading as "High Choice" and so on. The reason I'm here is because I have no clue how to do that. What makes it even harder is that not every page will have the same numbers, [here's an example of that](https://247sports.com/college/ohio-state/Season/2021-Football/Targets/). You'll see that while the picture from above only lists Top Target (3), this page now has Top Target (24). It varies for each page.

Would it be possible to alter my original script that would:

A) Creates that fifth column with the subcategory I mentioned above

B) Knows when it's suppose to switch to the next subcategory

C) Is agnostic to whatever the total number of people in each subcategory

EDITED script partially based on @Dave2e answer:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

teams <- c("ohio-state","penn-state","michigan","michigan-state")

targets_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/college/", teams, "/Season/2021-Football/Targets/")
# read the web page once! then extract the information requested

targets <- map_df(targets_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                    html_nodes(".ri-page__star-and-score .score , .position , .meta , .ri-page__name-link") %>%
                    html_text() %>% 
                    str_trim %>% 
                    str_split("   ") %>% 
                    matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>% 
                    as.data.frame)

#find the headings and the players
list <- page %>% html_nodes("li.ri-page__list-item")
headers <- which(html_attr(list, "class") == "ri-page__list-item list-header")
#find the category
category <- list[headers] %>% html_node("b.name") %>% html_text()

#extract repeats from header
nrepeats<-as.integer(str_extract(category, "[0-9]+"))

categories <- rep(category, nrepeats)[1:nrow(targets)]
#create combined dataframe
answer <- cbind(categories, targets)
```

Answer (score 0):

The headings are located at a "li" node with the class ="ri-page__list-item list-header".  It is also convenient to note the heading contains the number of players underneath that heading.
This script, finds the heading nodes, extracts the number of players and then creates the vector of repeating headings to merge to the targets dataframe.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

targets_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/college/ohio-state/Season/2021-Football/Targets/")
# read the web page once! then extract the information requested
page <- read_html(targets_url)

targets <- page %>%
            html_nodes(".ri-page__star-and-score .score , .position , .meta , .ri-page__name-link") %>%
             html_text() %>% 
             str_trim %>% 
             str_split("   ") %>% 
             matrix(ncol = 4, byrow = T) %>% 
             as.data.frame

#find the headings and the players
list <- page %>% html_nodes("li.ri-page__list-item")
headers <- which(html_attr(list, "class") == "ri-page__list-item list-header")
#find the category
category <- list[headers] %>% html_node("b.name") %>% html_text()

#extract repeats from header
nrepeats<-as.integer(str_extract(category, "[0-9]+"))

categories <- rep(category, nrepeats)[1:nrow(targets)]
#create combined dataframe
answer <- cbind(categories, targets)
```

*Update - finding the hidden data*
The webpage dynamically hides some information if the list is too long.  The cope can now handle that information.  The code below finds the hidden JSON data (contained in a 'script' node and parses that data.  It does return a list of players but not all of the same information.

```
#another option
#find the hidden JSON data
jsons <- page %>%   html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@type ="application/ld+json"]') 
allplayers <- jsonlite::fromJSON( html_text(jsons[2]))
#Similar list, provide URL to each players webpage
answer2 <- cbind(rep(category, nrepeats), allplayers$athlete)
```

Comment: This is outstanding work. Thank you so much. One more question though: If I switch out the URL with https://247sports.com/college/penn-state/Season/2021-Football/Targets/ it gets an error. Any insight on what's happening there?

Comment: Being a PSU alum, I should have started here. The error is due to the names at the end of the list not being shown on the initial page load. The data is hidden on the page. The solution is to ether to shorten `rep(category, nrepeats)` and/or access the hidden data.  See the updates above.  Another options is RSelenium.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have one more question. Checkout my edited answer. You'll noticed I'm mapping multiple teams to the script. While it runs without error, you'll notice that it only lists the "categories" for the first team in the list. Why is it doing that? Also, any suggestion on how I can add another column that lists which team it's affiliated with (so if he's on the Ohio State page link, it will say "Ohio State", if it's on the Penn State page it'll say "Penn State" etc...) It's okay if names repeat, there can be names attached to multiple pages.

Comment: What I would do:  is encase my entire solution in a  function taking the team name as the argument. Have the function create the URL and generate a data.frame of results and before returning the data frame from function add the team name as the extra column.  Use `lapply` or  "purrr" to call the function.  The result should be a list of dataframes which you can use `bind_rows()` to create the final grand dataframe.

Comment: Also notice I am only reading the webpage once into the variable "page" and the parsing that.  Your code is using  "targets_url" and the undefined variable "page"